# g++ warnings for variable shadowing in lambda expressions

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings, compiler-flags

Why does the following code generate a warning when it is compiled with `g++ -Wshadow -std=c++14`?

```
template<typename Function>
void f(Function g) {
  int x;
  g(0);
}

int main() {
  auto g = [](auto x) {};
  f(g);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation (assume this code is saved as `lambda_shadow.cc`):

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -Wshadow lambda_shadow.cc
lambda_shadow.cc: In instantiation of ‘main()::<lambda(auto:1)> [with auto:1 = int]’:
lambda_shadow.cc:4:6:   required from ‘void f(Function) [with Function = main()::<lambda(auto:1)>]’
lambda_shadow.cc:9:6:   required from here
lambda_shadow.cc:8:21: warning: declaration of ‘x’ shadows a previous local [-Wshadow]
   auto g = [](auto x) {};
                     ^
lambda_shadow.cc:3:7: note: shadowed declaration is here
   int x;
       ^
```

This warning is strange because g++ seems to follow the dynamic scoping rules.
I used g++ version 4.9.2 and 5.2.0, and clang++ 4.6 does not generate any warning.

In addition, I noticed that g++ compiles this code without warnings if a type of the lambda argument is specified (i.e., `auto g = [](int x) {};`).

Does anyone know the reason for this behavior? A bug of g++?

Comment: I'd say definitely a bug in g++.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'll report this as a bug.